# MATLAB: Clear directory except pre-specified files before running code

Tags: matlab, directory, delete-file

I want to build a Matlab code which clears a specified directory before I run my code. However, within this directory, there are 4 files which needs to remain there for correct functioning.

Currently, to remove a file from a directory I am using the following:

```
    AVLDir = External\AVL\
    delete([AVLDir obj.Data.FileId '*.dat']);
    delete([AVLDir obj.Data.FileId '*.avl']);
    delete([AVLDir obj.Data.FileId '*.key']);
```

Here, I need a file name and extension to be able to find the file and delete it. What I want is to delete everything in the folder `External\AVL\` except the following files:

```
avl.exe
avl_linux.txt
avl_mac (type of file is 'File') Don't exactly know what this is
avl_osx.txt
```

I want to do this to delete everything in the folder which might mess up my code since I am using the avl.exe externally.

How would I go about?

Comment: Use `dir` to get a list of all files. Then delete the files you want to keep and you know which you need to delete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the directory contents with `dir`, then compare the name of every non-folder item to your exclusion list and delete it if there's no match.

```
for d = dir('External\AVL').';
  if(~d.isdir && ~any(strcmp(d.name,{'avl.exe','avl_linux.txt','avl_mac','avl_osx.txt'})));
    delete(fullfile('External\AVL', d.name));
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Thanks! it seems to work and to do what I want. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Since this is about to "delete" files, it could be worthwhile to add the possibility to to move deleted files to recycle folder by using the [recycle](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/recycle.html) function.